# Checking if string array and listbox have any similarities

Tags: vb.net

Title says it all, I have been trying to figure out how to check if a listbox and a string array have any entries that are equal and have been unsuccessful.

```
Module Module1
    Public detectedMD5 As String() = {"944a1e869969dd8a4b64ca5e6ebc209a"}
End Module

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim procs() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
    Dim f As String

    For Each proc As Process In procs
        f = GetProcessFileName(proc)
        If f.Length > 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(GetMD5String(f))
        End If
    Next

    'Here is where I have been trying to compare the detectedMD5 string array to the listbox

End Sub
```

I did try doing something such as

```
    Do
        Try
            i = i + 1
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = i
            Dim detection As String
            For Each item As String In detectedMD5
                detection = InStr(ListBox1.SelectedItem, item)
                If detection > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Detected")
                End If
            Next
        Catch
            i = -1
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            Exit Do
        End Try
    Loop
```

But that didn't work, and got

```
 Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Comment: Loop through one list and, within that loop, loop through the other list to compare entries?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far so we can see where you are going wrong?

Comment: Just added the code in the OP, the rest of the code works as intended.

Comment: You can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: I tried using intersect, but I get a System.InvalidCastException error at " Dim intersection = detectedMD5.Intersect(ListBox1.Items)"

Comment: @GR8R8M8 you get a InvalidCastException because items is an objectcollection which doesn't contain intersect. Try `Dim intersection = detectedMD5.Intersect(ListBox1.items.Cast(Of Enumerable))`. _This might work but I haven't tested this_

Comment: @Cal-cium It still gave me the InvalidCastException, so I tried replacing the `(Of Enumerable)` with `(Of String)` and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @GR8R8M8 awesome. I will type it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it gives an InvalidCastException error is because you need to cast the ListBox.Items to String.

```
Dim intersection = detectedMD5.Intersect(ListBox1.items.Cast(Of String))
```